# Issue with Mouse.next() function when using multiple instances of a class

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm currently facing an issue with the `Mouse.next()` function, specifically when using multiple instances of a class. I'm working on implementing custom buttons, and to check if the left mouse button was pressed, I'm using the following code:

```
while(Mouse.next()) {
    if(Mouse.getEventButtonState() && Mouse.getEventButton() == 0) {
        // some code..
    }
}
```

This code works fine when I have only one instance of my button. However, when I add another instance of the button, the while loop never gets called for the second (last created) button.

I would appreciate any insights into why this could be happening. Additionally, I would like to understand the functions `Mouse.getEventButtonState()`, `Mouse.getEventButton() == 0`, and `Mouse.isButtonDown(0)` based on [org.lwjgl.input.Mouse](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Mouse.html).

So, how can I make the `Mouse.next()` function work correctly with multiple instances of the surrounding class?

Comment: What is `Mouse`? It's not in the JDK, so we can't help unless you tell us the library or show the code.

Comment: Also, what does "add another instance of the button" mean? Is the user pressing the mouse button a second time? Pressing a second mouse button at the same time? Or are you adding a button widget to your user interface?

Comment: Ia edited it now..

Comment: For an explanation of the methods, look at the documentation for `Mouse` by clicking on the link I added to your question.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't solve the problem with more then one instances with Mouse.next...

Answer (score 0):

Because Mouse is a Singleton . As long as it is Singleton calling next will consume the Event. You can not consume the same event two times! When first object calls next() it consumes it and when the second calls next() the is no second click to consume.

Comment: I think you're making assumptions about `Mouse`. It could be a factory creating new instances each time `.next()` is called. There's honestly no point in answering yet.

Comment: Come on look into the for loop, dont you see that it is calling again the Mouse :)  next() method returns true or false it does not return a Mouse :)

Comment: Of course, but methods can have side effects. It's pretty obvious that `Mouse` has a state that gets updated with each call to `next()`

Comment: Yes and this state is initialized as a result of the next() but without a new event the state is based on the last next(). And since there is no second click() the second for cycle is just returning false.

Comment: Now that the OP has edited, we can see that [`getEventButton()`](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Mouse.html#getEventButton()) will return -1 if the `next()` didn't retrieve a new event.

Comment: It is very nice chatting to you but here is the source code of the stupid thing and it is combination of Singleton plus state pattern http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl/2.8.0/org/lwjgl/input/Mouse.java#Mouse.create%28org.lwjgl.opengl.InputImplementation%29  take a look for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `getEventButton()` returns a different number depending on which button was pressed. What you should do instead is something like:

```
while (Mouse.next()) {
    if (Mouse.getEventButtonState()) {
        int buttonId = Mouse.getEventButton();
        switch (buttonId) {
            case -1: break; // no button was clicked
            case 0:
                // code for first button
                break;
            case 1:
                // code for second button
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the Mouse.next() function. In the first instance it returns true and in the second, third, etc.. it returns false..

This is the problem, the rest is working perfect..